# Is there a way to keep only rows in a DataFrame, when a column of that dataframe contains a substring of another column in that dataframe?

Tags: pandas, substring, rows, contains, similarity

I have a dataset:

```
                                  id                                   key            value
24                Apple Inc_Desktops    revenue_rgs_category_-_pc_monitors              nan
2                 Apple Inc_Desktops  revenue_rgs_category_-_mobile_phones 142381000000.000
46                Apple Inc_Desktops     revenue_rgs_category_-_smart_tech  24482000000.000
13                Apple Inc_Desktops    revenue_rgs_category_-_desktop_pcs  12870000000.000
35                Apple Inc_Desktops        revenue_rgs_category_-_tablets  21280000000.000
1                  Apple Inc_Laptops  revenue_rgs_category_-_mobile_phones 142381000000.000
45                 Apple Inc_Laptops     revenue_rgs_category_-_smart_tech  24482000000.000
23                 Apple Inc_Laptops    revenue_rgs_category_-_pc_monitors              nan
34                 Apple Inc_Laptops        revenue_rgs_category_-_tablets  21280000000.000
12                 Apple Inc_Laptops    revenue_rgs_category_-_desktop_pcs  12870000000.000
25            Apple Inc_MobilePhones    revenue_rgs_category_-_pc_monitors              nan
14            Apple Inc_MobilePhones    revenue_rgs_category_-_desktop_pcs  12870000000.000
36            Apple Inc_MobilePhones        revenue_rgs_category_-_tablets  21280000000.000
47            Apple Inc_MobilePhones     revenue_rgs_category_-_smart_tech  24482000000.000
3             Apple Inc_MobilePhones  revenue_rgs_category_-_mobile_phones 142381000000.000
```

And I only want to keep the rows when the column `key` contains a substring from column `id`. For example, as illustrated in the picture below, i want to keep only rows with index 13,3 because for those rows the 'key' column contains part of the `id` column - eg, for row with `index` 3, 'Mobile' is included in `key` column.

So my desired output would be:

```
                                  id                                   key            value
13                Apple Inc_Desktops    revenue_rgs_category_-_desktop_pcs  12870000000.000
3             Apple Inc_MobilePhones  revenue_rgs_category_-_mobile_phones 142381000000.000
```

I tried to create a new indicating whether the 'key' column contains substring of the 'id' column, but with not luck:

```
comp_rev_long['check'] = comp_rev_long['key'].str.contains('|'.join(comp_rev_long['id']),case=False)
```

Any ideas on an efficient way to do this? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: It would help if you can share some code so that we can replicate your dataframe and try to suggest a solution. Also it helps to know what you have been trying so far!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have fulfilled your requests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that should help you get started:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1)
# I create a simple DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": np.random.choice(["apple", "banana", "cherry"], 15),
                   "key":  np.random.choice(["apple pie", "banana pie", "cherry pie"], 15),
                   "value":    np.random.randint(0,20, 15)})
```

`df` looks like this:

```
        id         key  value
0   banana  cherry pie     13
1    apple  banana pie      9
2    apple  cherry pie      9
3   banana   apple pie      7
4   banana   apple pie      1
5    apple  cherry pie      0
6    apple   apple pie     17
7   banana  banana pie      8
8    apple  cherry pie     13
9   banana  cherry pie     19
10   apple   apple pie     15
11  cherry  banana pie     10
12  banana  banana pie      8
13  cherry  cherry pie      7
14   apple   apple pie      3
```

Here is a simple option to select only the rows that satisfy a certain condition.

```
# create a function that checks if a row satisfies your condition
check_condition = lambda row: row["id"] in row["key"]

# create a new column that determines whether you keep the row
# by applying the check_condition function row wise (-> axis=1)
df["keep_row"] =  df.apply(check_condition, axis=1)

# finally select and keep only the desired rows 
df = df[df["keep_row"]]
```

Now `df` looks like this:

```
        id         key  value  keep_row
6    apple   apple pie     17      True
7   banana  banana pie      8      True
10   apple   apple pie     15      True
12  banana  banana pie      8      True
13  cherry  cherry pie      7      True
14   apple   apple pie      3      True
```

One final issue is how to check if a substring is contained in another string. There are a few ways to go about this.

- Replace the values such that this operation becomes trivial, eg. `row["id"] in row["key"]`
- Make new columns with the crucial information of the sting, if you only need to know whether is a `mobile` or `pc` make a new 'device' column.
- Just code it anyway, this a a bit cumbersome though

This `check_condition` might work, form seeing your data but I cannot be sure of course.

```
def check_condition(row):
    for i in row["id"].lower().split('_'):
        if i in row["key"].lower():
            return True
        elif i[:-1] in row["key"].lower(): # account for the final 's'
            return True
    return False
```

2 notes:

1. This isn't a lambda function, but in this case it is equivalent to one, so you can replace the lambda `check_condition`-function by this one.
2. Also note that in the "id" and "key" columns some words ends with '-s' and some don't so that needs to be accounted for as well.

Comment: Andre, thanks for taking the time and responding in such detail. I will make sure to test it and get back to you, but it definitely seems promising!

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your question is to check if a string in your key column is present in the index column. In the example below, I construct a df (since you didn't provide one, with a column containing string in one column, present in another one:

```
import pandas as pd

a1,b2,c3 = 'ANDGFEEHsdsdSHSHS','FKDsdsdKSDKSDKS','DSLDJSLffsfsKDdSLDJS' 
s1, s2, s3 = 1,3,1
e1, e2, e3 = 3,6,6
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':[a1,b2,c3],'start': [s1, s2, s3],'end': [e1, e2, e3]})

df = df[['key', 'start', 'end']]
df['sliced'] = df.apply(fn, axis = 1)
aa1,bb2,cc3 = 'ANDGFEEHsdsdSHSHS','FKDsdsdKSDKSDKS','DSLDJSLffsfsKDdSLDJS' 
ss1, ss2, ss3 = 2,2,2
ee1, ee2, ee3 = 1,1,1
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[aa1,bb2,cc3],'start': [ss1, ss2, ss3],'end': [ee1, ee2, ee3]})
df2 = df2[['key', 'start', 'end']]
dff = df.append(df2)
```

[image]

You apply this to determine if string in one column exist in `key`:

```
df['Check'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.sliced in x.key, axis=1)
```

[image]
and slice for `True`.

Comment: Thanks for your repsponse. I have applied:

`comp_rev_long['check'] = comp_rev_long.apply(lambda x: x.id in x.key, axis=1)`

but unfortunately it does not give me what I need. For example, when the id is `Apple Inc_Desktops` and the key is  `revenue_rgs_category_-_desktop_pcs`, the code you wrote above gives a **False**.  Do you assume that my 'id' column should be the index of the dataframe?